# truncating df or file extension, nested loop using list.files and lapply

Tags: list, pdf, csv, directory, nested-loops

Is there an efficient way to read .csv files from a directory, where a .csv extension is needed, yet remove the .csv extension as the code loops through, writing a .pdf for each file?  Add another loop to trim off the .csv extension?

e.g., filename1.pdf, instead of filename1.csv.pdf.  (the former is what I want).

The code below works, assuming the files and field names exist.

Thanks for any comments.

```
ids<-list.files(path="C:/Program Files/R/R-2.12.2/STM/STM_A", pattern= "*.csv",       full.names=T,recursive=F)
lapply(ids, function(x)
    {       
a<-as.data.frame(read.csv(x, header=TRUE)) 
names(a)<-tolower(names(a))                                     
ptm<-proc.time()
pdf(file=(paste(x,".pdf"))) 
d_ply(a,"name",function(x) {
plot(data=x,value~site, xlab=names(a[1]), ylab=unique(x$metricname))
    })
dev.off()  
proc.time() -ptm 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There have been no comments and I've found an answer to my question so I'm passing it along.

The answer was to just rename the file with the sub function in the call to write the pdf file.

This code works, assuming the files and field names exist.

```
    ids<-list.files(path="C:/Program Files/R/R-2.12.2/STM/STM_A", pattern= "*.csv", full.names=T,recursive=F)
    lapply(ids, function(x)
{     
     a<-as.data.frame(read.csv(x, header=TRUE)) 
     names(a)<-tolower(names(a))                                     
     ptm<-proc.time()
     pdf(file=(paste(sub("[.][^.]*$", "", x),".pdf"))) 
     d_ply(a,"metricname",function(x) {
     plot(data=x,metricvalue~dcesystem.id, xlab=names(a[1]), ylab=unique(x$metricname))
     })
     dev.off()  
     proc.time() -ptm 
  })
```